# Rails : Database call inside a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, view

I'm building an ecommerce website from scratch.
Each product has many product details , each product_detail being [size,price_of_that_size,color,etc] for that product.

On my product controller i got :

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

The thing is on my index#view i need the price of the lowest product_details for that product , to be able to display the starting price of each product.

on my product#show controller i'm doing this to get that information :

```
@retailprice = @product.product_details.order("retail_price ASC").first
```

but on my Product#index i only have @products.all on which i'm already iterating on my view.

Is it bad practice to call

```
product.product_details.order("retail_price ASC").first
```

on each iteration in my view ?

I'm often in the need of ordering to display informations(asc / desc ) but when it's not very natural to do it in the controller i don't know where to put it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try create method in your model 
    def lowest_price_details
        product_details.order("retail_price ASC").first
    end 
and in template you can use like product.lowest_price_details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the sort order for the bare collection with an option on has_many itself:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many : product_details, :order => 'retail_price ASC'
end
```

You can also have two relations, and use them as par your requirement:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :product_details
  has_many :product_details_desc, :order => 'retail_price DESC'
  has_many :product_details_asc,  :order => 'retail_price ASC'
end
```